# CPU mysql hight value consumed

Tags: magento

Sometimes I get issue with connetion to database. I checked and when I open product then mysql CPU is 180 - 330% CPU.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what it might be? Magento 2 platform

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! How many processors does your machine have?

Comment: Please post complete TEXT results of htop and we will know how many CPU's your machine has.  Divide your %CPU displayed above by the number of CPU's on your server for AVERAGE CPU busy, please.  Avoid running investment applications on your MySQL hosting server to conserve power for your database users, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for all reply. Currently  4CPU 8 GB RAM, I think not enought in this case?

Comment: RAM may be fine. Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.